# How to make my existing ruby gem configuration available to my rails-api app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-api

I have a ruby gem I created that I've been using in one of my rails-api apps. I recently added a configuration to the gem, so I can configure it from my rails-api app, which would look like this:

```
# In rails-api app /config/initializers/my_gem.rb
MyGem::MyNamespace.configure do |config|
   config.allow_custom_commands = true
end
```

However, when I start the rails server, I'm getting a NoMethod error:

```
/Users/me/dev/rails/api.abc/config/initializers/my_gem.rb:61:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for MyGem::MyNamespace:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/me/dev/rails/api.mohojo-werks/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /Users/me/dev/rails/api.mohojo-werks/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
        from /Users/me/dev/rails/api.mohojo-werks/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency' 
etc.
```

All of my gem tests pass fine, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here are my config files:

```
# /my_gem/configuration.rb    
module MyGem
    module MyNamespace

        class Configuration
            attr_accessor :allow_custom_commands

            def initialize
            reset
            end

         public
            def reset
                @allow_custom_commands = false
            nil
            end
        end
    end
end


# /my_gem/configure.rb
module MyGem
    module MyNamespace
        class << self
            attr_writer :configuration
        end

        def self.configuration
            @configuration ||= Configuration.new
        end

        def self.configure
            yield(configuration)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have missed a few 'requires' in the below files. After adding them, everything seems to work fine, and my configuration block works fine in my rails-api app /config/initializers/my_gem.rb...

```
# my_gem.rb
require 'my_gem/configure'

# /my_gem/configure.rb
require_relative 'configuration'
```